# OSGi - why is my bundle named "unknown-0.0.0" and MANIFEST.MF file overwritten?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am new and am learning OSGi now. I'm trying to make maven project with OSGi MANIFEST.MF file inside it. After coding the bundle activator class and the MANIFEST.MF file, I "mvn package" it, and OSGi-install it in console. then this problem occurs where my bundle is named like this instead of the name when I mvn-package-ed it.

```
unknown-0.0.0
```

Then, when I checked the MANIFEST.MF file inside the .jar, the inside is like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: 5111100191
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.1
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_40
```

instead of when I coded it like this:

```
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.pragprog.HelloWorld
Bundle-Name: HelloWorld
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: com.pragprog.hello.HelloWorld
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
```

I'm guessing that the MANIFEST.MF that I code is somehow not loaded when I mvn package it. Here's my project directory structure

```
HelloWorld
           /src
                     /main
                            /java
                                       /com.pragprog.hello.HelloWorld.java
                            /resources
                                       /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
                     /test
                            /java
                            /resources
           /target
                     /**.jar file here**/
           pom.xml
```

I already searched for this, but couldnt find any clear solution. so how do I solve this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest using a OSGi specific Maven plugin, e.g. the [Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"mvn package", which uses the "maven-assembly-plugin" is not the correct way to create an OSGi bundle. Instead, you should use the "maven-bundle-plugin". [Here there is some documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) about how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at the new `bnd-maven-plugin` from the team at bndtools. http://njbartlett.name/2015/03/27/announcing-bnd-maven-plugin.html

The problem you have is that the maven jar plugin will ignore your manifest unless you configure the plugin with something like this in your pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```